# How can I wrap Play/JPA's Model class with a generic Repository?

Tags: java, jpa, persistence, playframework, repository-pattern

I don't like working with models objects directly, because this breaks encapsulation. Instead, I prefer the [Repository Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/repository-pattern).

When I try to implement a simple repository

```
public abstract class BaseRepository<T extends Model> {
    public T findOne(String query, Object... params) {
        GenericModel.JPAQuery result = T.find(query, params);
        return result.first();
    }
}
public class UserRepository extends BaseRepository<User>{}

UserRepository repo = new UserRepository();
repo.findOne("byUsername", "test");
```

I get exceptions because of the way java's generic or JPA annotations work:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Please annotate your JPA model with 
@javax.persistence.Entity annotation.
    at play.db.jpa.GenericModel.find(GenericModel.java:269)
    at repositories.BaseRepository.findOne(BaseRepository.java:12)
```

Is there a way around this?

(Needless to say the model is properly annotated, and when I use it directly with say `User.find("byUsername", "test").first()` it works well).

Comment: Can you provide the code sample where you actually make the call to `findOne()` that throws the exception?

Comment: @pHk - `UserRepository repo = new UserRepository(); repo.findOne("byUsername", "testy");`

Comment: That's odd. I'm afraid I'm not much help any more at the moment, but I'm really curious as to why this results in static calls to `GenericModel`.

Comment: @pHk - alright, thanks for trying to help. Can you delete your answer then, since it's not very relevant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not work because you are calling the static (class) method.

The [JPAEnhancer](https://github.com/playframework/play/blob/master/framework/src/play/db/jpa/JPAEnhancer.java) will at run time add the method to your class (User) but there is no polymorphism for types / static methods, it will always call the GenericModel one.

What you can **try** to do is get the actual parametric type with something like

```
ParameterizedType superclass = (ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
Class<?> aClass = (Class<?>) ((ParameterizedType) superclass).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
```

and the invoke method on that class..

Hope that helps...

Comment: This is the code I tried after your answer: https://gist.github.com/1370600 I'm getting an `argument type mismatch` exception when calling the invoke() method - perhaps it has something to do with the elipsis in the method arguments. Anyway, it seems a bit overkill for my application at the moment.

Comment: nice. The generic type constraints in the type cast actually didn't compile, so I dropped it. Here is a working complete example - https://gist.github.com/1370851